# Conditionally adding a new json.net JProperty

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible to create a new JProperty if an object contains a particular variable? For example:

```
string object = "var2";

var json = new JObject(
    new JProperty("var1", var1),
    if (object == "var2")
    {
        new JProperty("var2", var2)
    }
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is. Instead of declaring the extra property in the constructor, you can optionally [`Add`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Add.htm) it afterwards.

```
string myStr = "var2";

var json = new JObject(
    new JProperty("var1", var1));
if (myStr == "var2")
{
    json.Add(new JProperty("var2", var2));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this using a Dictionary and then I allow json.net to stitch it together at the end:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<string,object>();
temp["var1"]=var;
if(mystr=="var2"){
   temp["var2"] = var2;
}
//serialize the dictionary using JsonConvert method once you're done
```