# C#/json how do you insert a new property into the current property without a static location?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to add a new property to an existing property.  The property it is being added to can exist in different levels throughout the json file. (It's mechanical assembly).

I can get into child parameters, get their values and even delete them. However, i cannot figure out how to add a new property into the existing property - which is actually called properties.

As you can see from the code, i have to find the properties branch and then if the Stock Number is populated with an entry, i cache it, remove it, then remove the Part Number property as well.  All that works. I just cannot figure out how to add a new property back into properties after the fact.

```
var answers = jsonObject.Descendants()
                                    .Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                                    .Cast<JProperty>()
                                    .Where(x => x.Name == "properties").ToList();

            foreach (var ans in answers)
            {             
                var chlist = ans.Children().ToList();

                foreach (JObject item in ans.Children<JObject>())
                {
                    string stkNum = "";
                    foreach (JProperty prop in item.Properties())
                    {
                        if (prop.Name == "Stock Number")
                        {
                            stkNum = prop.Value.ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stkNum))
                            {
                                prop.Remove();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (JProperty prop in item.Properties())
                    {
                        if (prop.Name == "Part Number")
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stkNum))
                            {
                                prop.Remove();
                                
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stkNum))
                    {
                        //add new property here
                        
                    }


                }

                 
            }
```

I can attach a sample json, but it's lengthy.

```
{
    "id": "Root",
    "name": "PFUT-001-3000",
    "factoryName": "UtipGA",
    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    "parameters": {
        "ModelName": "Ruler-JZUtip",
        "Height": 120.0,
        "Width": 41.625,
        "Length": 41.625
    },
    "properties": {
        "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-3000",
        "Part Number": "GET PN",
        "Stock Number": "",
        "FolderKey": "Main",
        "EquipmentName": "Tip",
        "GroupType": "KES Projects",
        "rulerDrawingXml": "UtipGA.xml",
        "Project": "",
        "DrawingName": "PFUT-001-3000",
        "TAG_NO": "PFUT-001-3000-1",
        "Description": "U-36 FLARE TIP ASSEMBLY",
        "LiftingLugOrientation": 90.0,
        "LiftingLugSpacing": 180.0,
        "NumberOfPilots": 1,
        "Pilot1Angle": 30.0,
        "Pilot2Angle": 180.0,
        "Pilot3Angle": 240.0,
        "Pilot4Angle": 270.0,
        "NameplateOrientation": 180.0,
        "RetractablePilots": false,
        "DefLoc": "TUL"
    },
    "occurrences": [{
            "id": "Body",
            "selector": "Body",
            "factoryName": "UtipBody",
            "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
            "properties": {
                "rulerDrawingXml": "UtipGABody.xml",
                "DrawingName": "PFUT-001-7001",
                "TAG_NO": "PFUT-001-7001-1",
                "Description": "U-36 FLARE TIP BODY",
                "LiftingLugOrientation": 90.0,
                "LiftingLugSpacing": 180.0,
                "NumberOfPilots": 1,
                "Pilot1Angle": 30.0,
                "Pilot2Angle": 180.0,
                "Pilot3Angle": 240.0,
                "Pilot4Angle": 270.0,
                "WindscreenClipAngle": 30.0,
                "WindscreenClipNumber": 3,
                "NameplateOrientation": 180.0,
                "RetractablePilots": false,
                "Description": "U-36 FLARE TIP ASSEMBLY",
                "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001",
                "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-0",
                "Stock Number": "",
                "FolderKey": "Main",
                "EquipmentName": "Tip"
            },
            "occurrences": [{
                    "id": "RFFlange",
                    "selector": "RFFlange",
                    "factoryName": "RFFlange",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    "parameters": {
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "NOM": 36.0,
                        "O": 41.625,
                        "C1": 2.0625,
                        "X": 37.1875,
                        "A1": 36.0,
                        "Y": 4.5625,
                        "B": 35.5,
                        "BCD": 39.75,
                        "DH": 1.0,
                        "NU": 44,
                        "R": 38.25,
                        "RFH": 0.0625,
                        "SWB2": 0.111,
                        "SWD": 0.111
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-FLG-RFWN-36-150-A-105",
                        "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-20Xd",
                        "Stock Number": "FWN-304G360SB-001",
                        "FolderKey": "",
                        "EquipmentName": "Tip",
                        "Project": "",
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "TYPE": "RFWN",
                        "CLASS": "150",
                        "SCHEDULE": "STD",
                        "JZMaterial": "A-105",
                        "DefLoc": "TUL"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "Body",
                    "selector": "Body",
                    "factoryName": "RPlate",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.625, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    "parameters": {
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "Diameter": 36.0,
                        "NOM": 36.0,
                        "Thick": 0.25,
                        "Height": 55.375,
                        "Seam": 45.0,
                        "UpperDiameter": 18.0,
                        "RevolveAngle": 360.0,
                        "HoleDiameter": 0.0625,
                        "HoleElevation": 7.0,
                        "HoleOrientation": 90.0
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-LOWER-BODY",
                        "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-dSxL",
                        "Stock Number": "PLT-304A025-001",
                        "FolderKey": "",
                        "EquipmentName": "Tip",
                        "Stack": "0",
                        "ItemString": "lower",
                        "JZMaterial": "304",
                        "SHOP1": "CUT PER DWG",
                        "SHOP3": "",
                        "DefLoc": "TUL"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "UpperBody",
                    "selector": "UpperBody",
                    "factoryName": "RPlate",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    "parameters": {
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "Diameter": 36.0,
                        "NOM": 36.0,
                        "Thick": 0.25,
                        "Height": 60.0,
                        "Seam": 315.0,
                        "UpperDiameter": 18.0,
                        "RevolveAngle": 360.0,
                        "HoleDiameter": 0.0625,
                        "HoleElevation": 7.0,
                        "HoleOrientation": 90.0
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-UPPER-BODY",
                        "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFUT-001-7001-d5aI",
                        "Stock Number": "PLT-304A025-001",
                        "FolderKey": "",
                        "EquipmentName": "Tip",
                        "Stack": "0",
                        "TipTop": 1.0,
                        "ItemString": "upper",
                        "JZMaterial": "304",
                        "SHOP1": "CUT PER DWG",
                        "SHOP3": "",
                        "DefLoc": "TUL"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "UpperBracket1",
                    "selector": "UpperBracket1",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Brackets/CAST-0838/Upper Bracket/CAST-0838-1-310",
                    "matrix": [0.5, 0.0, 0.8660254, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 86.5, -0.8660254, 0.0, 0.5, -15.588457, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "LowerBracket1",
                    "selector": "LowerBracket1",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Brackets/CAST-0838/Lower Bracket/CAST-0838-3-310",
                    "matrix": [0.5, 0.0, 0.8660254, 9.1082535, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 42.125, -0.8660254, 0.0, 0.5, -15.525957, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "Nameplate",
                    "selector": "Nameplate",
                    "factoryName": "Components/Nameplate/ST-12160/ST-12160-1-304",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.7014455E-16, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9.311167, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "UAirrestorSTD",
                    "selector": "UAirrestorSTD",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Airrestor/304/AST-1243-36-304-ASSY",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.9604645E-08, 0.99999994, 5.625, 0.0, -0.99999994, 5.9604645E-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "LiftingLugs_1",
                    "selector": "LiftingLugs_1",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Lifting Lugs/CAST-1094-2-310",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "LiftingLugs_2",
                    "selector": "LiftingLugs_2",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Lifting Lugs/CAST-1094-2-310",
                    "matrix": [-1.0, 0.0, 8.742278E-08, -18.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 62.0, -8.742278E-08, 0.0, -1.0, 2.2043643E-15, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_1",
                    "selector": "FRS_1",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0654427E-15, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -17.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_2",
                    "selector": "FRS_2",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.98934335, 0.0, -0.14560118, 2.5334604, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.14560118, 0.0, 0.98934335, -17.214575, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_3",
                    "selector": "FRS_3",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.9576006, 0.0, -0.28809908, 5.012924, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.28809908, 0.0, 0.9576006, -16.66225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_4",
                    "selector": "FRS_4",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.90544826, 0.0, -0.42445672, 7.3855467, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.42445672, 0.0, 0.90544826, -15.754799, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_5",
                    "selector": "FRS_5",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.8339978, 0.0, -0.55176777, 9.600759, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.55176777, 0.0, 0.8339978, -14.511562, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_6",
                    "selector": "FRS_6",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.7447722, 0.0, -0.6673188, 11.611347, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.6673188, 0.0, 0.7447722, -12.959036, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_7",
                    "selector": "FRS_7",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.63967305, 0.0, -0.76864713, 13.37446, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.76864713, 0.0, 0.63967305, -11.130311, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_8",
                    "selector": "FRS_8",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.5209403, 0.0, -0.8535931, 14.85252, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.8535931, 0.0, 0.5209403, -9.064362, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_9",
                    "selector": "FRS_9",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.39110464, 0.0, -0.9203462, 16.014023, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.9203462, 0.0, 0.39110464, -6.805222, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_10",
                    "selector": "FRS_10",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.25293344, 0.0, -0.9674837, 16.834217, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.9674837, 0.0, 0.25293344, -4.401041, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_11",
                    "selector": "FRS_11",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.109371185, 0.0, -0.9940009, 17.295616, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.9940009, 0.0, 0.109371185, -1.903059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_12",
                    "selector": "FRS_12",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.03652203, 0.0, -0.99933285, 17.388391, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.99933285, 0.0, -0.03652203, 0.6354832, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_13",
                    "selector": "FRS_13",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.18163681, 0.0, -0.9833657, 17.110563, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.9833657, 0.0, -0.18163681, 3.1604812, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_14",
                    "selector": "FRS_14",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.3228805, 0.0, -0.94643974, 16.468052, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.94643974, 0.0, -0.3228805, 5.6181192, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_15",
                    "selector": "FRS_15",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.45724237, 0.0, -0.8893421, 15.474553, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.8893421, 0.0, -0.45724237, 7.9560165, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_16",
                    "selector": "FRS_16",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.5818591, 0.0, -0.8132897, 14.151241, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.8132897, 0.0, -0.5818591, 10.124345, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_17",
                    "selector": "FRS_17",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.6940743, 0.0, -0.71990347, 12.52632, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.71990347, 0.0, -0.6940743, 12.076891, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_18",
                    "selector": "FRS_18",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.79149663, 0.0, -0.61117345, 10.634422, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.61117345, 0.0, -0.79149663, 13.772038, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_19",
                    "selector": "FRS_19",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.87204945, 0.0, -0.48941785, 8.51587, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.48941785, 0.0, -0.87204945, 15.173659, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_20",
                    "selector": "FRS_20",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.934016, 0.0, -0.35723093, 6.2158175, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.35723093, 0.0, -0.934016, 16.25188, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_21",
                    "selector": "FRS_21",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.9760759, 0.0, -0.21743003, 3.7832851, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.21743003, 0.0, -0.9760759, 16.98372, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_22",
                    "selector": "FRS_22",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.9973322, 0.0, -0.0729952, 1.2701185, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, 0.0729952, 0.0, -0.9973322, 17.353582, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_23",
                    "selector": "FRS_23",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.9973322, 0.0, 0.07299538, -1.2701185, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.07299538, 0.0, -0.9973322, 17.353582, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_24",
                    "selector": "FRS_24",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.9760759, 0.0, 0.2174302, -3.7832851, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.2174302, 0.0, -0.9760759, 16.98372, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_25",
                    "selector": "FRS_25",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.934016, 0.0, 0.35723087, -6.2158175, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.35723087, 0.0, -0.934016, 16.25188, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_26",
                    "selector": "FRS_26",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.87204945, 0.0, 0.48941803, -8.51587, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.48941803, 0.0, -0.87204945, 15.173659, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_27",
                    "selector": "FRS_27",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.7914964, 0.0, 0.6111738, -10.634422, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.6111738, 0.0, -0.7914964, 13.772038, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_28",
                    "selector": "FRS_28",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.6940743, 0.0, 0.7199034, -12.52632, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.7199034, 0.0, -0.6940743, 12.076891, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_29",
                    "selector": "FRS_29",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.58185863, 0.0, 0.8132899, -14.151241, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.8132899, 0.0, -0.58185863, 10.124345, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_30",
                    "selector": "FRS_30",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.457242, 0.0, 0.8893422, -15.474553, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.8893422, 0.0, -0.457242, 7.9560165, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_31",
                    "selector": "FRS_31",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.32288027, 0.0, 0.94643986, -16.468052, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.94643986, 0.0, -0.32288027, 5.6181192, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_32",
                    "selector": "FRS_32",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.18163669, 0.0, 0.9833657, -17.110563, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.9833657, 0.0, -0.18163669, 3.1604812, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_33",
                    "selector": "FRS_33",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [-0.036521792, 0.0, 0.99933285, -17.388391, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.99933285, 0.0, -0.036521792, 0.6354832, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_34",
                    "selector": "FRS_34",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.109371364, 0.0, 0.9940009, -17.295616, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.9940009, 0.0, 0.109371364, -1.903059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_35",
                    "selector": "FRS_35",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.25293386, 0.0, 0.9674836, -16.834217, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.9674836, 0.0, 0.25293386, -4.401041, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_36",
                    "selector": "FRS_36",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.39110482, 0.0, 0.92034614, -16.014023, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.92034614, 0.0, 0.39110482, -6.805222, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_37",
                    "selector": "FRS_37",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.5209403, 0.0, 0.85359305, -14.85252, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.85359305, 0.0, 0.5209403, -9.064362, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_38",
                    "selector": "FRS_38",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.63967335, 0.0, 0.76864684, -13.37446, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.76864684, 0.0, 0.63967335, -11.130311, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_39",
                    "selector": "FRS_39",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.74477214, 0.0, 0.6673189, -11.611347, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.6673189, 0.0, 0.74477214, -12.959036, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_40",
                    "selector": "FRS_40",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.8339977, 0.0, 0.5517679, -9.600759, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.5517679, 0.0, 0.8339977, -14.511562, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_41",
                    "selector": "FRS_41",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.9054484, 0.0, 0.42445642, -7.3855467, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.42445642, 0.0, 0.9054484, -15.754799, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_42",
                    "selector": "FRS_42",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.95760065, 0.0, 0.28809884, -5.012924, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.28809884, 0.0, 0.95760065, -16.66225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }, {
                    "id": "FRS_43",
                    "selector": "FRS_43",
                    "factoryName": "Flare Components/Flare Tips/Flame Retention Segments/APAT-0387",
                    "matrix": [0.9893434, 0.0, 0.14560096, -2.5334604, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 118.5, -0.14560096, 0.0, 0.9893434, -17.214575, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id": "Pilot_1",
            "selector": "Pilot_1",
            "factoryName": "Standard",
            "matrix": [0.5, 0.0, 0.8660254, 9.875, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 89.5, -0.8660254, 0.0, 0.5, -17.104002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
            "properties": {
                "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFPT-001-3000",
                "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFPT-001-3000-0",
                "Stock Number": "",
                "FolderKey": "Main",
                "EquipmentName": "Pilots",
                "GroupType": "Flares",
                "DrawingName": "PFPT-001-3000",
                "TAG_NO": "PFPT-001-3000-1",
                "Description": "WP2 WINDPROOF PILOT ASSEMBLY",
                "DefLoc": "TUL"
            },
            "occurrences": [{
                    "id": "FFGCap",
                    "selector": "FFGCap",
                    "factoryName": "RFFlangeSW",
                    "matrix": [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.75, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -43.75, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    "parameters": {
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "NOM": 1.0,
                        "O": 4.25,
                        "C1": 0.5625,
                        "X": 1.9375,
                        "A1": 1.9221519,
                        "Y": 0.625,
                        "B": 1.36,
                        "BCD": 3.125,
                        "DH": 0.625,
                        "NU": 4,
                        "R": 2.0,
                        "RFH": 0.0625,
                        "SWB2": 1.049,
                        "SWD": 0.5
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "KFilename": "K98798MIK-PFPT-001-3000-FLG-RFSW-1-150-310",
                        "Part Number": "K98798MIK-PFPT-001-3000-NzxK",
                        "Stock Number": "FWS-311G1000",
                        "FolderKey": "",
                        "EquipmentName": "Pilots",
                        "Project": "",
                        "Ordinate": 0.0,
                        "TYPE": "RFSW",
                        "CLASS": "150",
                        "SCHEDULE": "STD",
                        "JZMaterial": "310",
                        "DefLoc": "TUL"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My expectation is to be able to add the new property into the list of properties contained in the properties property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally adding a new json.net JProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054885/conditionally-adding-a-new-json-net-jproperty)

Comment: I don't think so.  That's adding a variable off the root. This isn't off the root, it's wherever in the json the properties property is located for an entry.  Per the json, properties exists at different levels in the json.

Comment: shouldn't matter what level in the json, if it's a `JObject` there is an `Add` method for adding a new `JProperty`

Comment: I would think i should be able to do this at the 'ans' level, but i cannot come up with how.....someting like ans["New Property" = "new value", but that hasn't worked. Since the location changes every time, i can't just add with whole sequence from the root.

Comment: [M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm)